# Faster way to check if we can write message from given letters

Tags: java, performance, big-o

I needed to write a function that takes as input two strings. One is the message I want to write and second are given letters. Letters are ordered randomly.There is no guarantee that each letter occurs a similar number of times .some letters might be missing entirely. 
The function should determine if I can write message with the given
letters and it should return true or false accordingly.

I coded it and I think it is very fast, but how can I improve it having in mind the string with letters would be very large while the message would be very short?

Is there a fastest way?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class LetterBowl {

    public static void main(String []args){
        String message = generateRandomStringUpToThousandChars();
        String bowlWithLetters = generateRandomStringUpToThousandChars();

        if(canConstructMessage(message, bowlWithLetters)) {
            System.out.println("Message '" + message + "' can be constructed with letters from bowl : " + bowlWithLetters);
        }
     }


    public static boolean canConstructMessage(String message, String letters) {
        Map<Character,Integer> letterMap = stringToCharacterMap(letters);
        char[] messageList = stringToCharacterList(message);

        for(char c : messageList) {
            if (!containsLetterAndSubtract(c,letterMap))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    // checks if map(bowl) contains char andsubtract one char from map(or removes it if it is last one)
    public static boolean containsLetterAndSubtract(char c, Map<Character,Integer> letterMap) {
        if(letterMap.containsKey(c)) {
            if(letterMap.get(c) > 1) {
                letterMap.put(c, letterMap.get(c) - 1);
            } else {
                letterMap.remove(c);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static char[] stringToCharacterList(String message) {
        return message.replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
    }

    public static Map<Character,Integer> stringToCharacterMap(String s) {
        Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if(map.containsKey(c))
                map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            else
                map.put(c, 1);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static String generateRandomStringUpToThousandChars(){
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(1000); i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();

        return output;
    }; 

}
```

For large bowl size and smaller msg size i found this would be mor efficient :

public static boolean canConstructMessageSorted(String message, String bowlWithLetters) {
        int counter = 0;
        boolean hasLetter;

```
    //sorting
    char[] chars = bowlWithLetters.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sortedBowl = new String(chars);

    //sorting
    chars = message.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sortedMsg = new String(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedMsg.length(); i++) {
        hasLetter = false;
        for(  ; counter < sortedBowl.length() ; counter++) {
            if(sortedMsg.charAt(i) == sortedBowl.charAt(counter)) {
                hasLetter = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!hasLetter) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are the letters necessarily in English?

Comment: it is not necessarily. but english is ok for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You're operating at O(message.size + letters.size). This is the lowest worst-case time-complexity that I could figure out, on hand. Referring to the *fastest* way, there's always more you could do. For example, defining the method

```
public static char[] stringToCharacterList(String message)
```

and only using it once is technically time-inefficient. You could have simply put that body of code within the canConstructMessage() method, saving another item from being placed on, and taken off of the stack. Although this is such a small fragment of time, when you say *fastest*, it could be worth talking about.

Comment: is there a fastest way to do it, having in mind that we would always have small message string and long letter string (message could be 'abc' and letters could be "sabcjksdafofjifdhsf...... up to 10000 chars etc" ) ?
so we are looking for the fastest best-case scenario.
Would some other way of doing it be better?

Comment: @Juka I don't follow your interest in the *best-case scenario*. Typically, you want to improve your worst-case, or even average-case sometimes. When you talk about best-case scenario, you are finding an algorithm that has the *potential* for the fastest checking time. In that case, simply adding *if(message == letters){ return true;}* to the start of your function would be the *best-case scenario*, where you have 2 empty strings that are quickly checked in O(1) time. However, this is on *average* not the case, and will only slow the rest of your function down. If this didn't help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For every letter in `letters`, remove 1 copy of it from the message. If the message ends up empty, the answer is "yes":

```
public static boolean canConstructMessage(String message, String letters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++)
        message = message.replaceFirst("" + letters.charAt(i), "");
    return message.isEmpty();
}
```

If reusing letters is allowed, you can do it in 1 line:

```
public static boolean canConstructMessage(String message, String letters) {
    return letters.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet())
      .containsAll(message.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: this wont work for message="aaa", letters="abcdefgh" because you dont have enought letters "a" to form message.

Comment: @Juka I interpreted the question as allowing reuse of letters, but I think you're right (see edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this would be more efficient for large bowl size and small msg size :

```
public static boolean canConstructMessageSorted(String message, String bowlWithLetters) {
    int counter = 0;
    boolean hasLetter;

    //sorting
    char[] chars = bowlWithLetters.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sortedBowl = new String(chars);

    //sorting
    chars = message.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sortedMsg = new String(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedMsg.length(); i++) {
        hasLetter = false;
        for(  ; counter < sortedBowl.length() ; counter++) {
            if(sortedMsg.charAt(i) == sortedBowl.charAt(counter)) {
                hasLetter = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!hasLetter) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```